# HTML5 required fix for IE and Safari

Tags: html, forms, validation, required

Trying to implement 'required' attribute on IE<11 and Safari.

Here is the script I am using to try to accomplish this, but it isn't working. Looking for feedback or a slap in the face if necessary. The `form id = "sendit"`

```
$("#sendit").submit(function() {
 if (!attributeSupported("required") || ($.browser.safari)) {
  $("#sendit [required]").each(function(index) {
   if (!$(this).val()) {
    alert("Please fill all required fields.");
    return false;
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Try $("#sendit [required=required]") instead

Comment: What old version of jQuery are you using that $.browser works?

Comment: Try $("#sendit input[required=required]") maybe, the attr selector is sometimes a bit  particular

Comment: You should be checking for support like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550642/check-if-a-browser-has-built-in-html5-form-validation not with sniffing browsers. Did you debug the code to see what is failing? console.log() is your friend.

Comment: @epascarello the console says I am missing a `)` after the argument list, but I do not see that. Thank you for pointing out that this is old code. I removed $.browser `if` statement and replaced it with a `!` version of the `if` statement from your link

Comment: And what line does it point too for the missing )? My guess it is not this code

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I see it wasn't answered. The problem with your code is that you have the "return false" within the "each" function. That breaks out of the each loop but doesn't stop the form submit. I would just remove the browser checks since any browser that supports html5 form validation will pass the test. So you should be able to change the code to this:

```js
$("#sendit").submit(function() {
  var valid = true;
  $("#sendit [required]").each(function(index) {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      alert("Please fill all required fields.");
      valid = false
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!valid) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // anything else that need to be done on submit
});
```

Note that I added a line to focus the form field as well.